# Returning query data from a function to a jade/express.js page

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've been trying several different methods to try and take an array containing data from a SQL query using express.js an display it on a page using express and Jade templates. I've convoluted the process somehow by reading too many different methods of doing so, but I'm just not grasping the fundamental concept.

Essentially I have app.js with a function called fetchData that creates a connection to a DB2 database and stores the rows in an array. I'm able to see that printing out to the console log successfully. My problem lies in returning that array to the web page generated by express and Jade. I've used the tutorial and created the basic page using:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express'});
});
```

After that I've tried:

```
module.exports = router;

exports.init = fn1.fetchData();

exports.list = function (req ,res) {
  res.render('iData', { 'iData': dData });
}
```

But this for sure does not seem right and is not working when I attempt to display it using the jade template:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Howdy, welcome to #{title}
  ul
    for val in iData
      li= val
```

Does anyone know of a good guide or method to do what I'm trying to do? It seems fairly basic, I'm just not using the ingredients (node, express, jade) correctly.

Comment: where does your `dData` come from?

Comment: @malix There's a statement for parsing the rows into an array in my app .js

`else {
        var dData = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          console.log(rows[i]);
          dData.push(rows[i]);
            return dData;
        }
      }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your missing title variable is messing it up:

app.js

```
exports.list = function (req ,res) {
  res.render('iData', { 'iData': dData, title: 'something' });
}
```

iData.jade

```
h1= title
p Howdy, welcome to #{title}
ul
  for val in iData
    li= val
```

The Jade part seems to work fine:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZWYqx